# Get output of .change() function in .click() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have two radio buttons which both have values. When one is selected, and a button/link is clicked, the value of the selected radio button needs to be outputted to a text box.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form class="discount-choice" method="post" action="#">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" value="1" name="discount" id="1-month" class="discount-checkbox" />
            <label for="1-month">1 Month - no discount</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" value="0.95" name="discount" id="4-months" class="discount-checkbox" />
            <label for="4-months">4 months - 5% discount</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="get-result">Get Result</a>
    <input type="text" class="result" />
</form>
```

and my JavaScript (jQuery):

```
var discount = $(".discount-checkbox").on("click", function () {
    return this.value;
});

$(".get-result").on("click", function() {
    $(".result").attr("value", discount);
});
```

When I click the button (after having selected a radio button), I just get `[object Object]` in the text box.

I'm not sure of the syntax for setting a variable to be a jQuery function so this is likely where I am going wrong. If anyone could give me some guidance that would be awesome.

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: If I understand correctly you don't need to attach a click handler to `.discount-checkbox`, just get the value of the checked radio in the `.get-result` click handler: http://jsfiddle.net/9WQwL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Code:

```
var discount; 
$(".discount-checkbox").on("click", function () {
discount= this.value;
});
$(".get-result").on("click", function() {
$(".result").attr("value", discount);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`discount` is set to the jQuery object returned by `$(".discount-checkbox")`. You need to bind a click handler that updates a variable:

```
var discount = 0;
$(".discount-checkbox").on("click", function () {
    discount = this.value;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$(".get-result").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".result").val( $('.discount-checkbox:checked').val() );
});
```

You do not need the `click` handler on the `checkbox` as @billyonecan has mentioned in the comments.

And ... if you really need to attach an event handler to the `checkboxes`, that would be a `change` event handler instead of `click`.

Comment: hey, thanks for answering, this works but because my proper code is more complex than the example I posted, it needs to be in two functions. Thanks for helping anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

no need of discount-checkbox click event

```
$(".get-result").on("click", function() {
var discount = $(".discount-checkbox:checked").val();
$(".result").val(discount);
```

});

Comment: hey, thanks for answering, this works but due because my proper code is more complex than the example I posted, it needs to be in two functions. Thanks for helping anyway :)